# Display filtered result of an API via php - BatchData

Tags: javascript, php

Integrating the batchdata api and having problems displaying just one of the filtered items. there api example is: https://developer.batchdata.com/docs/batchdata/batchdata-v1/operations/create-a-property-skip-trace

In this example I'm trying to only display the phone number or email fields. The full result displays so I know the api is working...however, i can't display the filtered item just as:

```
<?php $email; ?>
<?php echo $response->response->results->result[0]->results->persons->email;?>
<?php echo $response->options->customProjection[0]->results->persons->phoneNumbers->number;?>
```

Here is the full code I have now:

```
<?php
$location = $entity->getSingleFieldValue('field_site_address');
$street = $location['street'];
$city = $location['city'];
$state = $location['province'];
$email = $response->response->results->result[0]->results->persons->email;

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.batchdata.com/api/v1/property/skip-trace",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"requests\": [\n    {\n
      \"propertyAddress\": {
        \"street\": \"$street\",
        \"city\": \"$city\",
        \"state\": \"$state\"
      }   }\n  ]\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ],
]);

$data = simplexml_load_string($result);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

?>

<?php
if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
  
}?>


<?php $email; ?>
<?php echo $response->response->results->result[0]->results->persons->email;?>
<?php echo $response->options->customProjection[0]->results->persons->phoneNumbers->number;?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to decode the JSON First before trying to access the fields

In your else statement add this

```
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response);
```

I'm not sure what the exact JSON response is that you are getting back but looking at the examples you might need to use this to get the email and phone number but without the actual response I can't confirm this **(don't post your actual reponse if it contains emails and phone numbers)**

```
$email = $decodedResponse->results->persons[0]->emails[0]->email;
$phoneNumber = $decodedResponse->results->persons[0]->phoneNumbers[0]->number;
```